# How to set the value of enum's properties from method?

Tags: java, enums

I have an Enum and it contains one property *(`age` in my case)*. I would like to set it's value from methods of each element. Below is my code..

```
enum Gender {
    MALE {
    void setAge() {
        this.age = 20;
    }
    },
    FEMALE {
    void setAge() {
        this.age = 30;
    }
    };
    int age;

    public int getAge() {
    return age;
    }

    abstract void setAge();
}

public class TestingEnum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Gender.MALE.getAge());
    System.out.println(Gender.FEMALE.getAge());

    }
}
```

But why producing their values in my main method show me only **0** ?

Comment: huh... because you never call setAge? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Apart from not needing the `setAge`-method in the first place (see _Jörn Buitink_'s answer below with a constructor), why do you have the age in a Gender-enum. :S This doesn't make any sense. If a future software developer would see your code and see `Gender.Male.getAge()` he/she will probably be quite confused.. Both gender and age should be a field in a Person-object or something similar; age inside the `Gender-enum` is just illogical..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No ... I already know about to set from constructor but I am trying to make an abstract method and set value from this abstract method. But one thing that I forgot to call this method. That is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never call setAge. You could use a constructor instead:

```
enum Gender {
    MALE (28),
    FEMALE (28);

    int age;

    Gender(int genderAge) {
        this.age = genderAge;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This! There is no need for an abstract method which each enum has to implement, when it's just setting some value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set The `Male` and `Female` ages like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gender.MALE.setAge();
    Gender.FEMALE.setAge();
System.out.println(Gender.MALE.getAge());
System.out.println(Gender.FEMALE.getAge());

}
```